# Alternating number of inputs per row in Bootstrap V3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form made in Bootstrap V3. The designer wants some rows to contain two inputs, while other rows contain only one.

I've made a fiddle here.
https://jsfiddle.net/06qk4wh4/

```
<div class="form-group  col-sm-12">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
        Label 1
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-md-4">
        Label 2
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-md-4">
        Label 3
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
        Label 4
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that in the row with two inputs I get an alignment error (shown in red in the image below). It works great in `col-sm-x`, because then it uses the full width. But in `col-md-x` I try to render two inputs in one row, and I get an "alignment error" because of the percentage calculation.

[image: alignment error shown in red]

**Is there a simple solution for this?** It must be a pretty common problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code.
It seems to fix your problem. I just add a row after your div(col-sm-12)

```
<div class="form-group  col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
            Label 1
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-md-4">
            Label 2
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-md-4">
            Label 3
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
            Label 4
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is the solution :)

Richie

Comment: It indeed solves the problem. Easy and elegant. Thanks alot!